# cv2.imread return NoneType while matplotlib.pyplot can read

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, pycharm

I have a problem while read an image using PyCharm. Let say that the path to my desire image is `D:/Trong/nam (10).jpg` (it has a space between `nam` and `(10)`).

Using opencv (installed by `pip install opencv-python`), my code for read this image is

```
import cv2
I = cv2.imread("D:/Trong/nam (10).jpg", 0)
```

and it return `NoneType` for `I`.

However, if I use `matplotlib.pyplot`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imread("D:/Trong/nam (10).jpg")
```

then it works. I don't know why this problem happens?

Furthermore, if I place that image to my program folder (which mean I just read by using `nam (10).jpg` only), then both methods can read.

Comment: did you try `"D:\\Trong\\nam (10).jpg"` ?

Comment: I tried `I = cv2.imread("D:/Trong/nam (10).jpg", 0)`, and it's working...

Comment: @furas i tried but failed

Comment: @Rotem because I have to work with multiple images, so instead of put a fix string to imread, I create a string variable (called as path), then I read by cv2.imread(path). It failed

Comment: you could use `os.listdir(folder)` to check if file exists in folder. You could also try to check if there is no space which you didn't see - at the end of name. You could use `print(len(name))` or `print(">{}<".format(name)` to seen it.

Comment: if you use variable then first you should check `print(path)` to see if you really created correct path. People sometimes forgot `/` between `folder` and `filename` or they get `filename` from `os.listdir(fodler)` and forgot to add `folder`